C# console app crashes when running batch file which exist in different directory
I have a batch file, which I need to run from my c# application. Batch file location is different from my c# console app exe location.
I'm trying below code, my c# console app crashes after calling Process.WaitForExit(), it is not even going to catch block.
Note : batch file ran successfully and produced expected result, but my c# application is crashing.
Bat file actually starting an exe, (to update one of my application)
         try
           {
                var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + "C:\Temp\batfile.bat");
                processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                processInfo.WorkingDirectory = "location of batfile.bat";
                processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                var process = Process.Start(processInfo);

                process.WaitForExit();

                if (process.ExitCode == 1)
                    isSuccessful = true;
                process.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //log
            }

I tried above method but it keeps on crashing.

ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + batfile.bat); won't compile unless you have an object variable named batfile that has a property named bat. Please show the actual code. Also, the error message/type could be helpful. Usually it says, what's wrong.

Actually, I do not get any error msg, the console app crashes abruptly.

As this is a console app, are you sure it's not just closing successfully? Try adding a console.read() after process.Close(). If the program pauses for input, then you know that the batchfile executed successfully without any errors.

You know that \ has a special meaning in strings? So "C:\Temp\batfile.bat" should probably be "C:\\Temp\\batfile.bat" or @"C:\Temp\batfile.bat"

After what line does it crash?

it executes until process.WaitForExit, and terminates after that.
